# download file in java from wampserver

Tags: java

i create java downloader and download 900MB file from my wampserver , and it works correctly , but when i check the Ram usage , it increase a lot , i dont know why?
i used IDM to download same file form my wampserver and it didnt use a lot of Ram 
when i see process and disk usage of my java downloader it take about 50MB and 5% cup but when i look to performance in Performance TAB , my RAM increase alot.

this is performance pic : https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfxNv.png

and this my code that my app create 8 thread to download this file simultaneously:

```
private void downloadFile() {
    try {
        this.response = this.con.getInputStream();
        this.bis = new BufferedInputStream(this.response, 32 * 1024);
                this.responseContentSize = this.con.getContentLength();


        if (this.responseContentSize == (this.end_range - this.start_range) + 1) {

                        int MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 32*1024;
            byte buffer[] = new byte[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
            makeTmpFile();
            out = new FileOutputStream(this.tmpdir + this.tmpFilename);
            bos = new BufferedOutputStream(out, 32 * 1024);

            while (true) {

                int r = this.bis.read(buffer, 0, this.MAX_BUFFER_SIZE);
                if (r == -1)
                    break;

                bos.write(buffer, 0, r);
                downloadedBytes += r;

            }

            if (bos != null)
                bos.close();
            if (out != null)
                out.close();
            if (bis != null)
                bis.close();
            if (response != null)
                response.close();

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        sharedDownloadStatus.setCell(this.threadIndex, STATUS, 0);//error
        log.setLog("func : downloadFile =>\n couldnt download file\n" + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You allocate data buffer for each chunk. They temporarily occupy a lot of memory befor garbage collector take care of them.

Try holding only one data buffer per thread. (Using ThreadLocal, for example).

Comment: which part of my code , you mean ? because my buffer array is out of while loop

Comment: Isn't this snippet run in cycle itself? You mention 8 threads.

Comment: ok i use 8 buffer with size of 32KB for 8thread that is 8 * 32 KB , so it doesnt take a lot of ram , so why occupy so much ? i dont understand your meaning ? sorry please explain it for me more

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `jvisualvm.exe` program to look at your memory consumption and see where its being allocated. `jvisualvm` is located in the bin folder of your jdk installation.

Heres what I would do to change your code:

- Get rid of the BufferedInput/BufferedOutput streams. These buffered streams are unnecessary in your program and are just adding in an additional memory allocation (of 32kb per buffered stream) but arent needed.
- Dont use 8 threads, I've build file download application to transfer very large files across networks and I have found the optimal amount of threads is 2 or 3. You cant download the file faster than your internet connection therefore adding in extra thread doesnt do anything but waste memory and time.
- Use a smaller buffer, a 32kb buffer is quite large, I would test using a smaller buffer like 1kb.
- Dont confuse wammp memory/cpu usage with your Java applications memory/cpu usage. Use the 'Processes' tab of the Windows Task Manager instead of the Performance tab.

With that said I dont have your entire program and cant test and debug performance for you but these are the things I would do. Below is your code that I have modified as much as possible.

---

```
private void downloadFile() {
    try {
        this.response = this.con.getInputStream();
        this.responseContentSize = this.con.getContentLength();


        if (this.responseContentSize == (this.end_range - this.start_range) + 1) {

            int MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
            byte buffer[] = new byte[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
            makeTmpFile();
            out = new FileOutputStream(this.tmpdir + this.tmpFilename);

            int r = 0;
            while ((r = response.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, r);
                downloadedBytes = r;

            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        sharedDownloadStatus.setCell(this.threadIndex, STATUS, 0);//error
        log.setLog("func : downloadFile =>\n couldnt download file\n" + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (out != null)
            out.close();
        if (response != null)
            response.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you for informative response , its very helpful thanks , but why IDM download manager create 8 thread for downloading and it doesnt consume lot memory ??

Comment: @wineo how do you know the IDM downloader uses 8? Also it may use up to 8 and not always 8. Consider if you were using a super fast computer and internet. In that case 8 threads might be optimal given the circumstances. Now consider a old 56k connection, do you think 8 threads would speed up a 56kb per second speed cap?... probably not. Also I would ask if you want further diagnosis you post some jvisualvm stats on your program. Currently as per your post it is not identifiable where your memory drain is coming from... for all we know its waamp

Comment: and can you email me your downloader project to my email => mr [dot] jahankhah [at] yahoo [dot] com ?

Comment: yes im ganna run this software on my vps with 1Gbps network speed ,any way your response was very usefull for me that can trust java more than befor

Comment: this is my stats of my program by jvirsualvm : http://i.imgur.com/IIRtIKv.png  , why heap is so much large , because i create downloader in C# and it take 20MB ram but in java it goes up to 70MB , why ?

Comment: @wineo Given the information provided I cant really draw any conclusions. I would be happy to look into it a bit more but we should continue this conversation in a chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139/java . I will be in there for a bit.